# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.learning' has no attribute 'assign_weights_to_keras_model'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

```
eval_model = None
for round_num in range(1, 51):
    state, tff_metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
    eval_model = create_keras_model()
    eval_model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.3),loss=losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),metrics=[metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
    tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model(eval_model, state.model)
    ev_result = eval_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print('round {:2d}, metrics={}'.format(round_num, tff_metrics))
    print(f"Eval loss : {ev_result[0]} and Eval accuracy : {ev_result[1]}")
    tff_train_acc.append(float(tff_metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy))
    tff_val_acc.append(ev_result[1])
    tff_train_loss.append(float(tff_metrics.loss))
    tff_val_loss.append(ev_result[0])
```

It throws an error that we cannot assign weights. Earlier it was working.

Comment: Please format your code and include the full traceback error.

Answer (score 1):

`tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model` was removed in version [0.17.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/releases/tag/v0.17.0) and was replaced by [`tff.learning.ModelWeights.assign_weights_to`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/ModelWeights#assign_weights_to)

Try replacing

```py
tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model(eval_model, state.model)
```

with

```py
state.model.assign_weights_to(eval_model)
```

Comment: I tried but did not work.

AttributeError: The tuple of length 2 does not have named field "assign_weights_to". Fields (up to first 10): ['trainable', 'non_trainable']


keras_model =  create_keras_model()

state = tff.learning.state_with_new_model_weights(
    state,
    trainable_weights=[v.numpy() for v in keras_model.trainable_weights],
    non_trainable_weights=[
        v.numpy() for v in keras_model.non_trainable_weights
    ])

Comment: This then depends on how `iterative_process` was created and possibly what version of `TFF` is being used. Could the question be extended to include this information?

Comment: Hi @ZacharyGarrett, I have the same issue. `state.model.assign_weights_to(eval_model)` worked in tff 0.27 but does not work in 0.28. Has it been changed?

Comment: @ZacharyGarrett I faced same problem in 0.57.0 'state.model.assign_weights_to(eval_model)' didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [TFF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_text_generation)

```
model_weights = iterative_process.get_model_weights(state)
model_weights.assign_weights_to(eval_model)
```

However, need to change `tff_metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy` to `tff_metrics['client_work']['train']['sparse_categorical_accuracy']` and `tff_metrics.loss` to `tff_metrics['client_work']['train']['loss']`.